# Why is my Google CSE form formatted so poorly cross-browser?

Tags: css, google-custom-search

I'm using a Google CSE on http://afv.com and the results page is so wonky for Firefox and Safari. Here's what I see:

**Chrome (looks perfect):**

[image]

**Firefox (magnifying glass gone in blue button, text falls out bottom of input field):**

[image]

**Safari (input field far too wide, sends blue button off edge of page):**

[image]

I've mucked around with the style sheet Google gives me, to try to override some styles and standardize the output, but I can't see why it's so weird across browsers. Any thoughts? I know using a CSE is a bit of a hack and I'm having to shoehorn it into my layout, but these pictures show some incorrect layouts (or in the case of Safari, *wildly* incorrect), beyond just minor formatting issues.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because some of your own css is influencing the search button (e.g. a library like bootstrap or a css reset). If you try a search button without any additional styles - e.g. this one:

`enter code here`http://jsfiddle.net/buQL3/1/show_html/

it should render correctly (renders well for me in OS X 10.8.5 latest Chrome, Firefox 24 and Safari 6.0.5).